# Coffeescript / Node.js - How to remove elements from an object based on comparison with DB

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I'm working on a project which will post periodic XML updates for users.  I'm attempting to suppress information which hasn't changed since the last update.

Within node.js, I have assembled a user object which will be used to generate the XML:

```
users = 
  # actual application has 25 properties per user
  [
    {
      USERID: 150927,
      EMAIL: 'irving.block@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Irving',
      LASTNAME: 'Block',
      COLOR: 'Green'
    },
    {
      USERID: 1246007,
      EMAIL: 'allen.adler@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Adler',
      LASTNAME: 'Allen',
      COLOR: 'Blue'
    },
    {
      CLKEY: 1248350,
      EMAIL: 'walter.pidgeon@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Walter',
      LASTNAME: 'Pidgeon',
      COLOR: 'Red'
    }
  ]
```

I also have an object loaded which helps map user data to the eventual XML fields:

```
xml_map =
  [
    {
      ID: 1,
      ELEMENT: 'xml_map_assigned_id',
      MAPPPED: 'USERID' 
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      ELEMENT: 'xml_map_email_address',
      MAPPPED: 'EMAIL' 
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      ELEMENT: 'xml_map_user_firstname',
      MAPPPED: 'FIRSTNAME' 
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      ELEMENT: 'xml_map_user_lastname',
      MAPPPED: 'LASTNAME' 
    },
    {
      ID: 5,
      ELEMENT: 'xml_map_user_color',
      MAPPED: 'COLOR'
    }
  ]
```

Using these objects, I need to compare with the last update, and remove matching properties (since I only want to post updates for data that has changed).  Here's an example of what the last update (stored in the DB) might look like:

```
# nothing like this is used in the real application
# just showing here to give an idea of what the DB could look like
db_data = 
  [ 
    {
      USERID: 150927,
      EMAIL: 'irving.block@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'IRVING',
      LASTNAME: 'Block',
      COLOR: 'Orange'
    },
    {
      USERID: 1246007,
      EMAIL: 'new.email@somewhere.com',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Adler',
      LASTNAME: 'Allen',
      COLOR: 'Blue'
    },
    {
      USERID: 1248350,
      EMAIL: 'walter.pidgeon@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Walt',
      LASTNAME: 'Pidgeon',
      COLOR: 'Red'
    }
  ]
```

Using these examples, I'd like to end up with a User object like this (since only 1 thing has changed for each user):

```
users_final = 
  [
    {
      USERID: 150927,
      COLOR: 'Orange'
    },
    {
      USERID: 1246007,
      EMAIL: 'new.email@somewhere.com',
    },
    {
      USERID: 1248350,
      FIRSTNAME: 'Walt',
    }
  ]
```

And now for the pseudo-code that shows how I've been trying to accomplish this:

```
async = require "async"

handleChanges = (users, map, callback) ->
  sql1 = "select..."
  sql2 = "update..."
  sql3 = "insert..."
  db.query sql1, [], (err, rows, def) ->
    if err? then console.log err
    if rows[0]
      if rows[0].ELEMENT_VALUE.toString() is users[map.MAPPED].toString() 
      # nothing has changed since last update
        db.query sql2, ['Old'], (err, rows, def) ->
          if err? then console.log err
          callback null, map.MAPPED
      else # this value has changed since the last update. Run update query
        db.query sql2, ['New'], (err, rows, def) ->
          if err? then console.log err
          callback null, null
    else # no value has ever been saved for this combo. Run insert query
      db.query sql3, [], (err, rows, def) ->
        if err? then console.log err
        callback null, null

updateStore = (users, callback) ->
  for map in xml_map
    do(map) ->
      handleChanges users, map, (err, del) ->
        if del? then delete r[del]
  callback null, r

async.map users, updateStore, (err, results) ->
  console.log results
```

This obviously doesn't work right.  I'm sure the updateStore function needs to be doing something different, but I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you render your data on client side or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar thing in the project, but I use json instead of xml.

What I have done is
retrieve a list of objects from db. and calculate a hash value for each of the object.

```
users = 
  [
    {
      USERID: 150927,
      EMAIL: 'irving.block@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Irving',
      LASTNAME: 'Block',
      COLOR: 'Green'
    },
    {
      USERID: 1246007,
      EMAIL: 'allen.adler@email.net',
      FIRSTNAME: 'Adler',
      LASTNAME: 'Allen',
      COLOR: 'Blue'
    }
  ]
hash = [
  'c8addc875913a367486ba8343f68e349667e0334',
  'df3d067e876437996237d0fde90466703ea303b9'
]
```

on the client side, I do compare the each old hash to the new hash. if different I use php.js or underscore.js. php.js can do array_diff to get differents between two object. Of course you can just do array_diff with comparing hash.

If your data structure is nested like this

```
{
  User: {
    FIRSTNAME: 'Irving',
    LASTNAME: 'Block',
    USERID: 150927
  }
  OtherInfo: {
    EMAIL: 'irving.block@email.net'
  }
}
```

you can flatten it to following before doing array_diff because array_diff only work on one level.

```
{
  "User.FIRSTNAME": 'Irving',
  "User.LASTNAME": 'Block',
  "User.USERID": 150927,
  "OtherInfo.EMAIL": 'irving.block@email.net'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the ideas; I like how you're doing that.  I also prefer JSON, but our client requested XML.  I _could_ build a duplicate DB object and perform an array_diff to eliminate the common denominators.  However, everything is already developed to check each property against the DB individually (to account for easily adding/removing elements in the future).  Also, code is already written to convert my Users object to XML - I just need to remove the silly elements that match...asynchronous nature of node.js is making that difficult.  Would be easier to build a second User object.

Comment: unless someone can suggest a way to accomplish this the way I'd like, I'll probably end up doing something similar to how you've suggested (was my 'Plan B' anyways).  If that's what I ultimately end up doing, I'll mark your response as 'The Answer' and post some updated code =P

Comment: using array_diff you should get your desire output as 
`users_final =  
  [  
    {  
      USERID: 150927,  
      COLOR: 'Orange'  
    },  
    {  
      USERID: 1246007,  
      EMAIL: 'new.email@somewhere.com',  
    },  
    {  
      USERID: 1248350,  
      FIRSTNAME: 'Walt',  
    }  
  ]`
so you can transform this to xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is enough information about your expected XML output for me to help there, but the `users_final` result you are looking for can be calculated with a fairly straight forward comparison algorithm. The core algorithm is:

```
difference = (a, b, idFieldName) ->
  if a[idFieldName] != b[idFieldName]
    throw new Error("#{idFieldName} values must match.")
  diff = {}
  diff[idFieldName] = a[idFieldName]
  isDifferent = false
  for key, value of b
    if key != idFieldName and a[key].toUpperCase() != value.toUpperCase()
      isDifferent = true
      diff[key] = value
  if isDifferent
    return diff
  else
    return false
```

[Here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ausers%20=%20%0A%20%20#%20actual%20application%20has%2025%20properties%20per%20user%0A%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%20150927,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27irving.block@email.net%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27Irving%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Block%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Green%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%201246007,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27allen.adler@email.net%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27Adler%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Allen%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Blue%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%201248350,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27walter.pidgeon@email.net%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27Walter%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Pidgeon%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Red%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%0Adb_data%20=%20%0A%20%20%5B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%20150927,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27irving.block@email.net%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27IRVING%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Block%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Orange%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%201246007,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27new.email@somewhere.com%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27Adler%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Allen%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Blue%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20USERID%3a%201248350,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EMAIL%3a%20%27walter.pidgeon@email.net%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FIRSTNAME%3a%20%27Walt%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LASTNAME%3a%20%27Pidgeon%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20COLOR%3a%20%27Red%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%0Adifference%20=%20%28a,%20b,%20idFieldName%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20if%20a%5BidFieldName%5D%20!=%20b%5BidFieldName%5D%0A%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22#%7BidFieldName%7D%20values%20must%20match.%22%29%0A%20%20diff%20=%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20diff%5BidFieldName%5D%20=%20a%5BidFieldName%5D%0A%20%20isDifferent%20=%20false%0A%20%20for%20key,%20value%20of%20b%0A%20%20%20%20if%20key%20!=%20idFieldName%20and%20a%5Bkey%5D.toUpperCase%28%29%20!=%20value.toUpperCase%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isDifferent%20=%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20diff%5Bkey%5D%20=%20value%0A%20%20if%20isDifferent%0A%20%20%20%20return%20diff%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%0A%0AarrayToMap%20=%20%28a,%20idFieldName%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20result%20=%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20for%20row%20in%20a%0A%20%20%20%20if%20result%5Brow%5BidFieldName%5D%5D?%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error%28%22#%7BidFieldName%7D%20values%20must%20be%20unique%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20result%5Brow%5BidFieldName%5D%5D%20=%20row%0A%20%20return%20result%0A%0AidFieldName%20=%20%27USERID%27%0A%0AusersMap%20=%20arrayToMap%28users,%20idFieldName%29%0A%0Ausers_final%20=%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20b%20in%20db_data%0A%20%20a%20=%20usersMap%5Bb%5BidFieldName%5D%5D%0A%20%20diff%20=%20difference%28a,%20b,%20idFieldName%29%0A%20%20if%20diff%0A%20%20%20%20users_final.push%28diff%29%0A%0Aalert%28JSON.stringify%28users_final,%20undefined,%202%29%29%0A) is a fully working example including using the input you provided... with one exception. I think you have a typo in your `users` literal. I switched it from `CLKEY` to `USERID` so it matches the other rows. Just click on the "Run" button in the upper right hand corner after following the link to see your expected `users_final` result.

Comment: Thanks for that diff function - that will come in handy!  Apologies for not responding sooner - had all day yesterday to think about how I'd like to do this while I worked on some other projects.  I'll hopefully resolve it today.

Comment: Be sure to follow the link under the "Here" to the full working answer. If you like it, I'd appreciate the vote and maybe even a "checkmark" indicating that you accepted the answer.